# What was the significance of Goliath's spear shaft being like a weaver's rod in 1 Samuel 17:7?

Tags: 1-samuel

1 Samuel 17:7

> His spear shaft was like a **weaver's rod**, and its iron point weighed six hundred shekels. His shield bearer went ahead of him.

Why was this simile important?

Comment: Down-vote cancelled (+1). Good question. All scripture has spiritual meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 Sam 17:4-7 contains a description of the Philistine champion, Goliath, every element of which was design to show how large, heavy, strong and otherwise invincible he was.  Specifically, "He was ...

1. six cubits and a span in height (about 3m or 10 ft high)
2. he had a bronze helmet on his head
3. He wore a bronze coat of mail weighing five thousand shekels (about 57 kg or 126 lb)
4. he had armor of bronze on his legs
5. and a javelin of bronze slung between his shoulders
6. The shaft of his spear was like a weaver’s beam
7. its iron point [lit. "flame" because it was polished and shining] weighed six hundred shekels (almost 7 kg or 15 lb)
8. In addition, his shield bearer went before him.
9. he has been a warrior from his youth (V33)
10. In V51 we are also told that Goliath had large sword.  See also 1 Sam 21:9, 22:10.

These weapons appeared almost superhuman as ordinary men would not have strength to even pick them up much less use them.  Thus, Goliath was "armed to the teeth", large, strong, frightening, well trained, impregnable, etc.  The whole purpose is to increase the magnitude and drama of the victory that David accomplished in the name of the LORD/YHWH -

> David added, “The LORD, who delivered me from the claws of the lion
> and the bear, will deliver me from the hand of this Philistine.”  1
> Sam 17:33

The Story is essentially concluded by saying (V50, 51):

> Thus David prevailed over the Philistine with a sling and a stone;
> without a sword in his hand he struck down the Philistine and killed
> him ... When the Philistines saw that their hero was dead, they turned
> and ran.

Answer (score 1):

New Living Translation
The shaft of his spear was as heavy and thick as a weaver’s beam, tipped with an iron spearhead that weighed 15 pounds. His armor bearer walked ahead of him carrying a shield.

The simile shows his spear was intimidatingly thick. It serves as a contrast to David who is naked and unprotected. Nevertheless, David wasn't afraid even though he didn't even have a sword with him.

45David replied to the Philistine, “You come to me with sword, spear, and javelin, but I come to you in the name of the LORD of Heaven’s Armies—the God of the armies of Israel, whom you have defied. 46Today the LORD will conquer you, and I will kill you and cut off your head.

How? By using Goliath's own sword. That's the irony. It's dramatic with all the suspense.

Answer (score 0):

The significance is the weapon itself.
It could be long and thick, enough to hold such a weighted head, but what else does a weaver's beam have? Some type of rope curling around it.
Goliath's spear was unique (at least from our perspective and time period) in that there was a wrapped cord around it, where Goliath could put let's say, two fingers in it. You throw the spear, using the cord, you have a very dangerous weapon. Almost as or maybe just as dangerous as a sling.
Also, fun fact: according to the Bible, Goliath's weapons were also light enough for anyone to carry, same with his armor, as he was stripped of armor and weapons by the Israelites and later David used Goliath's sword.

Comment: Could you provide a scriptural reference for "according to the Bible, Goliath's weapons were also light enough for anyone to carry"?

Comment: There is a wealth of spiritual allusion in weaving : the shuttle, the warp and the weft.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics.  Please take ourTour to see what we look for for in well-researched answers: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour